# Android APIs to Auto answer the call and read DTMF tones

Tags: android, ivr, dtmf

I would like to know the following whether possible with Android or not. I keep searching on line but no luck. I feel that may be possible with new versions of the Android. I want check with experts on Stackoverflow.

1. Shall I Auto answer the call and play a pre-defined Audio file? At this time, we should not use Micro phone or Speaker.
2. Once we Auto answer the Call, shall we play pre-defined Audio files based on the DTMF tones received from other end? Do we have Native APIs to read and the DTMF tones? - Simply, can I build a "IVR System" as an Android App? (asking too much? send me your suggestions)
3. Shall we record the telephony streams as Audio files? We can write a trans-coder if we have access to the streams using the native APIs.

I may be asking too much here, because am a new to android and did not find any absolute answer online.

Thanks in Advance,
- PC Varma